# Regex search in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I use this code in php to detect whether there is five same symbols in a row in the string and execute some code if it does.

```
function symbolsInRow($string, $limit = 5) {
    $regex = '/(.)\1{'.($limit - 1).',}/us';
    return 0 == preg_match($regex, $string);
}
```

Now I need to do the same thing in javascript, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with it enough. How can be this function converted into javascript? The function should return false if it finds 5 same symbols in row in the given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
function symbolsInRow(string, limit) {
   // set the parameter to 5 if it is not provided
    limit = (limit || 5); 

    // create a regexp object, initialized with the regex you want. we escape the \ with \\ because it is a special char in javascript strings.
    var regex =  new RegExp('(.)\\1{'+(limit-1)+',}'); 

    // return false if we find a match (true if no match is found)
    return !regex.test(string); 
}
```

the actual `test` method will return true if it finds a match. So notice the `!` which is the `not` operator inverting the result of the test, since you wanted to return false if it found a sequence.

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/aPTAb/

Comment: Newlines? `g` has nothing to do with newlines.

Comment: @Victor, you are right.. i used a wrong example in my test, and thought the the `g` flag corrected it, but it wasn't that..

Answer (score 1):

May be not with a regexp:

```
function symbolsInRow(str, limit, symbol){
    return str.split(symbol).length === limit + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to do it using regex if it's possible because I need to perform the check for each symbol individually. None of the symbols in the string should be used more than five times in a row but it can be used at any amount in different places. For example this "somethiiiiiiiiing" should return false but "somethininininining" shouldn't...

Comment: The original problem asks for **any** symbol (that is, you can't expect the caller to know what `symbol` is...) to be repeated five times **in a row** (so `aaa-aa` would not return `true`).

Comment: a bad translation from "in a row" to "sur une ligne" in my french speaking brain...

Answer (score 1):

This should be equivalent:

```
function symbolsInRow(string, limit) {
    limit = (limit || 5) - 1;
    return !(new RegExp('(.)\\1{'+limit+'}')).test(string);
}
```

Comment: In Javascript regular expressions, the modifier `u` is unnecessary and `s` is the default (one has to use `m` to go back to multiline mode).

Comment: Now you need to turn that '\' into an '\\' ;)

Comment: This function always return false! I checked this: alert(symboldInRow("somethiiiiiiing", 5)); and this: alert(symboldInRow("something", 5)); and in both cases it returned false, while in second case it should have returned true.

Comment: @Victor Nicollet: Thanks! Forgot about that! @Levani: It works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

For five case-sensitive characters in a row, this should work:

```
function symbolsInRow(string) {
  return /(.)\1{4}/.test(string);
}
```

If you need to match an arbitrary number of repetitions:

```
function symbolsInRow(string,limit) {
  return (new RegExp('(.)\\1{'+limit+'}')).test(string);
}
```